# Splitting a Hibernate entity class into a class hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, inheritance, composition

I have a table called Product and the respective Hibernate entity class called Product.java.

There are different types and subtypes of Products that are distinguished by two columns in the table called "type" and "subtype". In the application, conceptually they are different things. As in, there should ideally be a Product class hierarchy, but unfortunately a lot of code has been implemented in the one entity model class with if conditions and switch cases.

I am looking for ways to refactor this into a class hierarchy. I have come up with a few options, but I am not convinced that they are the best ways to go about it and I am looking for feedback and suggestions.

1. Hibernate's table-per-class-hierarchy: This is nice, but it looks like this decision should have been made when the code was first written. Now, since the Product class is already implemented and is core to the project, I do not think it will be an easy task to follow this approach. Also, the main advantage of this approach seems like the ability to have different fields specified in different subclasses. That does not fit well for us because the Product object should only behave differently in the application, but the variables/data that is stored in the row is required by all subclasses of "Products". Can I have one parent class that has defined all the entity variables and the subclasses have no variables at all?
2. Composition: Make classes for different types of Products but each of these classes will contain a Product variable. This could work to some extent since I can keep all the common code in the Product class itself, but move all customized code to these classes.

I could use some feedback/suggestions as to what the best way to go ahead and refactor that class.

Comment: You probably want a joined subclass model rather than table-per-class, which is difficult to deal with polymorphically.

Comment: I cannot break up the variables or the existing table. The schema cannot change that dramatically since we are going to have to run queries to fill the data up on production. Also, I said table per class hierarchy, not table per class.

Comment: Then what you're looking for is called "single table". `TABLE_PER_CLASS` is a specific term in JPA and refers to having separate tables for each concrete type. And it's unclear, apparently, what you mean by "break up the variables"; if certain properties only exist on certain subclasses, the usual relational approach is to join them.